# Compromising design & code quality to integrate with existing modules

Tags: oop, refactoring

Greetings!

I inherited a C#.NET application I have been extending and improving for a while now. Overall it was obviously a rush-job (or whoever wrote it was seemingly less competent than myself). The app pulls some data from an embedded device & displays and manipulates it. At the core is a communications thread in the main application form which executes a 600+ lines of code method which calls functions all over the place, implementing a state machine - lots of if-state-then-do type code. Interaction with the device is done by setting the state/mode globally and letting the thread do it's thing. (This is just one example of the badness of the code - overall it is not very OO-like, it reminds of the style of embedded C code the device firmware is written in).

My problem is that this piece of code is central to the application. The software, communications protocol or device firmware are not documented at all. Obviously to carry on with my work I have to interact with this code.

What I would like some guidance on, is whether it is worth scrapping this code & trying to piece together something more reasonable from the information I can reverse engineer? I can't decide! The reason I don't want to refactor is because the code already works, and changing it will surely be a long, laborious and unpleasant task. On the flip side, not refactoring means I have to sometimes compromise the design of other modules so that I may call my code from this state machine!

I've heard of "If it ain't broke don't fix it!", so I am wondering if it should apply when "it" is influencing the design of future code! Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: The key here is to make sure that you're refactoring i.e. improving the structure *without modifying behavior*. And for that you'd need to retrofit tests onto that core, before you make any changes. No one likes broken code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the constraints you are facing, it's a decision to be based on practical basis, not on theoretical ones. You need three things to consider.

1. Time: you need to have enough time to learn it, implement it, and test it, without too many other tasks interrupting you
2. Boss #1: if you are working for someone, he needs to know and approve the time and effort you will spend immediately, required to rebuild your solution
3. Boss #2: your boss also needs to know that the advantage of having new and clean software will come at the price of possible regressions, and therefore at the beginning of the deployment there may be unexpected bugs

If you have those three, then go ahead and refactor it. It will be surely be worth it!

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely recommend you to refactor the code if you feel its junky. Yes, during the process of refactoring you may have some inconsistencies/problems at the start. But that is why we have iterations and testing. Since you are going to build up on this core engine in future, why not make the basement as stable as possible.

However, be very sure on what you are going to do. Because at times long lines of code does not necessarily mean evil. On the other hand they may be very efficient in running time. If/else blocks are not bad if you ask me, as they are very intelligent in branching from a microprocessor's perspective. So, you will have to be judgmental and very clear before you touch this.

But once you refactor the code, you will definitely have fine control over it. And don't forget to document it!! Tomorrow, someone might very well come and say about you on whatever you've told about this guy who have written that core code.

Answer (score 2):

Also, the longer you wait, the worse the codebase will smell. My suggestion would be first create a testsuite that you can evaluate your refactoring against. This makes it a lot easier to see if you are refactoring or just plain breaking things :).

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, get all the business logic out of the Form.  Second, locate all the parts where the code interacts with the global state (e.g. accessing the embedded system).  Delegate all this access to methods.  Then, move these methods into a new class and create an instance in the class's constructor.  Finally, [inject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) an instance for the class to use.

Following these steps, you can move your embedded system logic ("existing module") to a wrapper class you write, so the interface can be nice and clean and more manageable.  Then you can better tackle refactoring the monster method because there is less global state to worry about (only local state).

Answer (score 1):

If the code works and **you can** integrate your part with minimal changes to it then let the code as it is and do your integration.

If the code is simply **a big barrier** in your way to add new functionality then it is best for you to refactor it.

Talk with other people that are responsible for the project, explain the situation, give an estimation explaining the benefits gained after refactoring the code and I'm sure (I hope) that the best choice will be made. It is best to speak about what you think, don't keep anything inside, especially if this affects your productivity, motivation etc.

**NOTE:** Usually rewriting code is out of the question but depending on situation and amount of code needed to be rewritten the decision may vary.

Answer (score 1):

You say that this is having an impact on the future design of the system. In this case I would say it is broken and does need fixing.

But you do have to take into account the business requirements. Often reality gets in the way!

Would it be possible to wrap this code up in another class whose interface better suits how you want to take the system forward? ([See adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern))

- This would allow you to move forward with your requirements without the poor design having an impact.
- It gives you an interface that you understand which you could write some unit tests for. These tests can be based on what your design requires from this code. It ensures that your assumptions about what it is doing is correct. If you say that this code works, then any failing tests may be that your assumptions are incorrect.

Once you have these tests you can safely refactor - one step at a time, and when you have some spare time or when it is needed - as per business requirements.

Quite often I find the best way to truly understand a piece of code is to refactor it.

**EDIT**

On reflection, as this is one big method with multiple calls to the outside world, you are going to need some kind of inverse Adapter class to wrap this method. If you can inject dependencies into the method (see [Dependency Inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) such that the method calls methods in your classes then you can route these to the original calls.